# How can I compare ecoinvent's LCIA scores to the characterized inventory in Brightway2?

Tags: brightway

I am digging into Brightway2 for a research project using ecoinvent version 3.9.1. As I want to calculate different scenarios, I am not interested in a particular foreground system for now, but rather arrive at the matrix of Footprint multipliers (C*B*A^-1).  As a first step, I want to compare the results stored in Brightways lca.characterized_inventory object to the LCIA results provided by ecoinvent in excel format (downloadable via licence on their website). I have chosen 'ReCiPe 2016 v1.03, midpoint (H) no LT','material resources: metals/minerals no LT','surplus ore potential (SOP) no LT' as an LCIA method and I want to know if everything went well while importing ecoinvent into Brightway i.e. how well the LCIA results match with the excel file.

For me it boils down to a problem with interpreting the characterized inventory. How do I map it's matrix values to actual activity names I can search for in the excel file? I found that the activity UUID_Product UUIDs identifiers in the excel file do not match those created by Brightway. Why is that?
For example: according to ecoinvent, ferronickel production has an impact of 1,39 kg Cu-Eq per kilogram. How and where do I find this number in my Brightway2 inventory?
I want to end up with a plot showing ecoinvent lcia scores on one axis and Brightway scores on the other, sorted by activity.

I have of course loaded ecoinvent and computed the lca.
I don't remember where I got this from but I think I summed over characterization factors (?) to store the lcia results by activity inside a structured numpy array:

```
results_by_activity = (lca.characterized_inventory.sum(axis=0)).A1
```

I have created a pandas series that is supposed to store both activity names and impacts:

```
list_of_names_in_columns = [bw.get_activity(rev_act_dict[col])['name'] 
                            for col in range(lca.characterized_inventory.shape[1])]
pd.Series(index=list_of_names_in_columns, data=results_by_activity).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

I have also loaded my excel sheet into a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

ei_lcia_score_file = r'C:my_file_path\Cut-off_Cumulative_LCIA_v391.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(ei_lcia_score_file, sheet_name='LCIA', header = [0,1,2])
#use previously selected LCIA method to select a method column from the ecoinvent file
ei_lcia_midpoint_scores = df[LCIA_method]
```

I have been reading about reverse dictionaries storing activity names and biosphere flows here:
[Connecting exchange names and codes to LCA inventory results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494583/connecting-exchange-names-and-codes-to-lca-inventory-results)

I'm still confused.

I would appreciate any help, as I am getting stuck with my project.

Answer (score 0):

The characterised inventory has as columns activities and as rows characterised elementary flows. if you sum by rows you'll get for each activity the contributions of its *direct* emissions to the LCIA score of the activity you are calculating. If you aggregate the columns you'll get the contribution per elementary flow. If I am not mistaken is the result of: $$C B s^{-1}$$ where is *s* is the solution to the linear system f = A s. You don't need to calculate the inverse for that, but you can if you need it.

You could try something like this for the calculation, I hope that with the comments it would be enough to understand the logic. The end result is a

```py
import bw2calc as bc
import bw2data as bd
import pandas as pd

lca = bc.LCA({ecoinvent_act:1},recipe_method)
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()

# get the leointief inverse
L = lca.invert_technosphere_matrix()

# matrix with biosphere flows as rows activities as cols
B = lca.biosphere_matrix.todense()

# matrix with characterization factors
 C = lca.characterization_matrix.todense()

# LCIA contribution, characterized elementary flows as rows
# activities as columns
score_matrix = (C @ B @ L)

# aggregate per activity
scores = score_matrix.sum(axis=0)

# here we pick the names of the activities in the columns of
# the matrices
names = [(bd.get_node(id=i)['name'],bd.get_node(id=i)['location']) 
for i in lca.activity_dict]

pd.Series(scores.A1,index=names)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately, my Brightway version does not seem to know the lca.invert_technosphere_matrix() method, throwing an attribute error : 'LCA' object has no attribute 'invert_technosphere_matrix'. I am using bw2calc version 1.8.2 and bw2data version 3.6.6. Is there a workaround or should I downgrade to some other version?

Comment: that method seems to have been added in version 2.0.dev4

Comment: (https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-calc/blob/main/CHANGES.md). The current version is 2.0.dev13. If it's possible for you the easiest would be to upgrade. Otherwise you can invert yourself the techno-sphere using numpy